# Using randomly selected points uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1) find the volume of the unit sphere

Tags: random, spheres

I've been given this extra credit assignment to do in Matlab, but I don't understand the question. The part that I'm not clear about is where I have to satisfy the equation x+7+z>1.

Can someone clarify this for me.

> Using randomly selected points uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1) find the volume of the unit sphere with the center in the origin, that satisfy the equation x+y+z>1.
>
> Obtain the results with number of randomly selected points equal 100, 1000, and 10000

Comment: $x+y+z = 1$ defines a plane, so you are looking for a region bounded by the sphere and this plane.